# Python Pareto Chart issue

Tags: python, pareto-chart

Trying to get a `pareto-chart` in Python following

I am following this code in my Jupyter notebook
[How to make Pareto Chart in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577630/how-to-make-pareto-chart-in-python/53578962#53578962)

I'm not getting the pareto increasing uniformly, instead its zigzag and the x-labels are sorted alphabetically, instead of ordered by `country` though the `df.sort_values` is there.

Please suggest what could be the issue.

[image: Python-Pareto-Issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that matplotlib (aka plt) forces the alphetical sort for old versions of matplotlib (when did you last uprade it ?). You can see more informations and a great answer on solutions and workarounds here : [How to prevent alphabetical sorting for python bars with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647875/how-to-prevent-alphabetical-sorting-for-python-bars-with-matplotlib)
In particular, just set a numerical index :

```py
df['Nation'] = ['USA', 'Canada', 'Russia', 'UK', 'Belgium', 'Mexico', 'Germany', 'Denmark']
```

Then `df.index` will keep numerical order.

Comment: Upgrading matplotlib version solved the issue ! Thanks so much!